# Make the wiki more worthwhile, or rules for first time posters on a tag

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tag-wiki

I realize this question has probably been asked in a different light, but in certain tags the wiki is loaded with useful debugging, template, tutorial information that would really cut down on the basic questions.

What's the chance of forcing a first time poster for a tag into viewing the wiki?  Or recommending they read the wiki before posting a question with a certain tag?

Comment: I would expect some users to just skip over the wiki, even if you force them to view it once, but if this prevents even a few RTFM questions, it could be worthwhile.

Comment: It would require more rigorous formatting and higher quality for tag wikis than currently exists.

Comment: What about an opt in approach?  I feel like I go through and toss a ton of helper info into the tag wiki, then I spend half of my time referencing it for new people.  I realize you'll still have your lazy people who don't want to put forth the effort of reading, they just want to copy and paste code, but maybe it'd help a group of people.